# Redirect domain to other domain on same server without changing visible url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I've been wondering for a while if it is possible at all to redirect a (sub)domainname to another domain without changing the visible url using `.htaccess` or PHP / similar language if the domains are on the same server (shared hosting). I know it would be a security issue if the domains are not on the same server, and therefor not possible, but is there a way to redirect `hostname.com` to for example `client.hostname2.com`, and keeping `hostname.com` as visible url?

For example with something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^hostname.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://client.hostname2.com/$1 [P]
```

Ofcourse all parameters / maps etc. after `hostname.com` should be redirected properly. I've seen quite a few questions about this, but none of them really go in depth about the domains being on a shared hosting instead of being random domains.

**Just to be clear: The domains are on the same server!**

Comment: Redirect using mask url.... it should be available in your hosting

Comment: Do the main domain and subdomain point to the same folder on your server (or: do they share the same document root)?

Comment: @Sumurai8 At the moment this is not the case, but I can make that happen: Would it be possible that way?

Comment: If you don't want to change the url in the browser, you are doing an internal rewrite. You basically rewrite the internal representation to point to a different file on the same server. You don't need a proxy to do this if both domains are on the same server. If they have exactly the same document root, a request to `hostname.com/asdf` and `client.hostname2.com/asdf` would serve exactly the same content without any rules. If one of the document roots is a subfolder of the other document root, you can use a rewriterule to bridge that gap. I am unsure if it is otherwise possible.

Comment: Alright, I will look into that. Thanks @Sumurai8. Make sure to turn your comment into an answer if you would like to, so I can accept it.

Comment: I currently don't have the time to write a fully fleshed out answer right now. Feel free to use the information in my comment, and all else you learn on the way and answer your own question ;-)